# Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop package installed, but can't launch "gnome-terminal", "cannot open display"

Tags: 12.04, gnome

I have install Ubuntu desktop packages on a 12.04 LTS server. X server comes up fine, GUI works fine without any issues.

However, when I tried to issue a terminal, I get `Cannot open display`, I find this strange since the X Display is running.

Here's a link of the screen I took from VNC viewer:

[image]

Comment: What graphics card do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the DISPLAY environment variable:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

If it helps, you can append this line to your `.bashrc`.